# How to add comma separate in sprintf PHP?

Tags: php

I have a loop like this:

```php
foreach ($imported_data as $index => $product_data) {
    $Str = sprintf('"%s"',$imported_data[$index][0]);
    $result = str_replace('""', '","', $Str);
    echo $result;
}
```

result is:

```
"200728J70JNY08""200728JQ05Y4S4""200730QWVD1DDQ""200728H2QS7M9Y"
```

I want my string to be:

```
"200728J70JNY08","200728JQ05Y4S4","200730QWVD1DDQ","200728H2QS7M9Y"
```

Comment: `join(',' array_map(function ($s) { return "\"$s[0]\""; }, $imported_data))`…?

Comment: What is this specific text format you’re trying to cobble together here? CSV? SQL? JSON? Might there be an existing function that can do this easily and safely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it:

```
$Str = '';
foreach ($imported_data as $index => $product_data) {
    $Str .= sprintf('"%s"',$imported_data[$index][0]);
}
$result = str_replace('""', '","', $Str);
echo $result;
```

Comment: @SatrioDwiPrabowo leaving that kind of comment is not the way here. What you can do, though is to [accept the given answer and/or upvote it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).